# Facebook connect mutli domain

Tags: facebook

Please excuse my bad English, I'm French ;)

So I've a problem with my website.
The Facebook connexion works fine with http://mywebsite.fr BUT NOT with http://www.mywebsite.fr

Do you know why ?

Thanks

Comment: There's settings for app domains in your app settings section. You can enable subdomains here (e.g www.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your app settings and set

*.mywebsite.fr

in the "app domains" section